# In WinRT Metro App C#, where is the ConstructorInfo.ReflectedType?

Tags: reflection, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

It's been removed and I was curious if it was located somewhere else in the Reflection API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Reflection is removed including the members you've mentioned. This is to make sure that an app that passes certification, doesn't call non-public APIs through Reflection.